# How to change value for innodb_buffer_pool_size in MySQL on Mac OS?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am trying to increase the size of the innodb_buffer_pool_size in MySQL 5.1 as I keep running into the following error indicating I have run out of space for the table locks.

```
ERROR: The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size
Error
Code: 1206
```

I have gone through the documentation and from what I gather, I need to update innodb_buffer_pool_size in the /etc/my.cnf file. My current value is 8M. However, even after creating that file and adding the following line to set the value it is not updating in MySQL.

```
set-variable=innodb_buffer_pool_size=256M
```

Does have any advice on how I can adjust this value in MySQL on my mac? Any other advice or suggestions?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

add this to your my.cnf

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=1G
```

restart your mysql to make it effect

Comment: thanks for your help. I added what you suggested with no success. I checked the innodb_buffer_pool_size after and it was still 8M. My file is /etc/my.cnf. Should it be in a different location? do I need anything else in the file?

Comment: @analyticsPierce may be your mysql config file is ~/.my.cnf,how do you start mysql?, try to use this script http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-server.html

Comment: I am running on a Mac and MySQL is started when I start my laptop, done through a preference setting.

Comment: @analyicsPierce does the ~/.my.cnf exist？

Comment: It did not. I added it and it did not make a difference. same problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: On Ubuntu (and quite possibly other linux distros), the `my.cnf` file is at `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` not `/etc/my.cnf`.

Comment: it is also recommended to increase 'innodb_buffer_pool_instances' when using 1G or more buffer size.  it will usually improve performance.

Comment: restart mysql using this command ```sudo service mysqld stop``` & ```sudo service mysqld start``` Or ```sudo service mysql stop``` & ```sudo service mysql start```

Answer (score 39):

In the earlier versions of **MySQL ( < 5.7.5 )** the only way to set

> 'innodb_buffer_pool_size'

variable was by writing it to **my.cnf (for linux)** and **my.ini (for windows)** under [mysqld] section :

```
[mysqld]

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2147483648
```

*You need to restart your mysql server to have it's effect in action.*

### **UPDATE :**

> As of MySQL 5.7.5, the innodb_buffer_pool_size configuration option
>   can be set dynamically using a SET statement, allowing you to resize
>   the buffer pool without restarting the server. For example:
>
> ```
> mysql> SET GLOBAL innodb_buffer_pool_size=402653184;
> ```

Reference : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-buffer-pool-resize.html

Comment: `ERROR 1238 (HY000): Variable 'innodb_buffer_pool_size' is a read only variable`

Comment: `mysql> SET GLOBAL innodb_buffer_pool_size=402653184;` this worked for me, but this reset when you restart. So have to fire `same query` if you restart mysql.

Answer (score 28):

I had to put the statement under the [mysqld] block to make it work. Otherwise the change was not reflected. I have a REL distribution.

Comment: sorry, this was meant to be a feedback in the previous answer. I was referring to put innodb_buffer_pool_size=1G inside the [mysqld] section.

Answer (score 3):

For standard OS X installations of MySQL you will find my.cnf located in the /etc/ folder.

Steps to update this variable:

1. Load Terminal.
2. Type `cd /etc/`.
3. `sudo vi my.cnf`.
4. This file should already exist (if not please use `sudo find / -name 'my.cnf' 2>1` - this will hide the errors and only report the successfile file location).
5. Using vi(m) find the line `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, press `i` to start making changes.
6. When finished, press esc, shift+colon and type `wq`.
7. Profit (done).

Comment: "locate my.cnf" ("sudo updatedb" if its not found) will be much faster than a find from root, especially on a large file system.

If you cannot use locate yet, take a look at http://osxdaily.com/2011/11/02/enable-and-use-the-locate-command-in-the-mac-os-x-terminal/

Comment: Good addition, it appears to be a sort of cached search function. Thanks Eric.

Answer (score 3):

As stated,

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=50M
```

Following the convention on the other predefined variables, make sure there is no space either side of the equals sign.

Then run

```
sudo service mysqld stop
sudo service mysqld start
```

**Note**

Sometimes, e.g. on Ubuntu, the MySQL daemon is named `mysql` as opposed to `mysqld`

I find that running `/etc/init.d/mysqld restart` doesn't always work and you may get an error like

```
Stopping mysqld:                                           [FAILED]
Starting mysqld:                                           [  OK  ]
```

To see if the variable has been set, run `show variables` and see if the value has been updated.