# How to transfer bulk data (millions) from one table to another table

Tags: mysql

I have a table t1 with 30 fields and want to transfer only 15 fields data to another table. How to do that? t1 has 1.5 million records

Comment: I am doing batch update 10000 rec at a time after 950000 it showing 'number of locks exceeded' error. Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size" Deleting 267 Records](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253482/the-total-number-of-locks-exceeds-the-lock-table-size-deleting-267-records)

Answer (score 1):

First step count your records . Then run this query :

```
INSERT INTO `tbl2` SELECT * FROM `tb1` LIMIT COUNT/2;
```

tbl2 structure should be like tbl1 .

Otherwise see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482443/how-to-copy-data-from-one-table-to-another-new-table-in-mysql) topic

Comment: I don'w want all the fields from the tb1

Answer (score 0):

Above mentioned link will help you to query . But i have a suggestion , you shouldn't run the query directly ,If it is any production db. You should write a stored procedure and transfer records chunk by chunk . check  [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html)