# error 1206 whenever trying to delete records from a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with more than 40 million records.i want to delete about 150000 records with a sql query:

```
DELETE
FROM t
WHERE date="2013-11-24"
```

but I get error 1206(The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size).
I searched a lot and change the buffer pool size:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=3GB
```

but it didn't work.
I also tried to lock tables but didn't work too:

```
Lock Tables t write;
DELETE
FROM t
WHERE date="2013-11-24";
unlock tables;
```

I know one solution is to split the process of deleting but i want this be my last option.
I am using mysql server, server OS is centos and server Ram is 4GB.

I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you restart mysql after changing the variable?

Comment: Do you have any triggers on the table `DELETE`?

Comment: i have restarted the mysql after changing.

Comment: i don't have a delete table. i want to delete records from table "t" which it doesn't have any constraint.

Comment: How big is your data? 4GB RAM and allocating 3GB to the pool size will make your server choke.

Comment: the current table size is 20GB.

Comment: I'm sure you have a huge database! Delete your boss records or ask him to buy a better server!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Limit` on your delete and try deleting data in batches of say 10,000 records at a time as:

```
DELETE
FROM t
WHERE date="2013-11-24"
LIMIT 10000
```

You can also include an ORDER BY clause so that rows are deleted in the order specified by the clause:

```
DELETE
FROM t
WHERE date="2013-11-24"
ORDER BY primary_key_column
LIMIT 10000
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but as i said before,I want splitting the deleting process be my last option. I am looking for any solution like changing configuration mysql server or server os.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of quirky ways this error can occur. I will try to list one or two and perhaps the analogy holds true for someone reading this at some point.

On larger datasets even when changing `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to a larger value, you can hit this error when an adequate index is not in place to isolate the rows in the where clause. Or in some cases with the primary index (see [this](https://major.io/2010/02/16/mysql-the-total-number-of-locks-exceeds-the-lock-table-size-2/)) and the comment from Roger Gammans:

> From the (5.0 documentation for innodb):-
>
> If you have no indexes suitable for your statement and MySQL must scan
>   the entire table to process the statement, every row of the table
>   becomes locked, which in turn blocks all inserts by other users to the
>   table. It is important to create good indexes so that your queries do
>   not unnecessarily scan many rows.

A visual of how this error can occur and difficult to solve is with this simple schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `students` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `thing` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `campusId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `ix_stu_cam` (`camId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

A table with 50 Million rows. FK's not shown, not the issue. This table was originally for showing query performance also not important. Yet, in initializing `thing`=`id` in blocks of 1M rows, I had to perform a limit during the block update to prevent other problems, by using:

```
update students 
set thing=id 
where thing!=id 
order by id desc
limit 1000000 ; -- 1 Million
```

This was all well until it got down to say 600000 left to update as seen by

```
select count(*) from students where thing!=id;
```

Why I was doing that `count(*)` stemmed from repeated

> Error 1206: The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size

I could keep lowering my LIMIT shown in the above update, but in the end I would be left, say, with 1200 `!=` in the count, and the problem just continued.

Why did it continue? Because the system filled the lock table as it scanned this large table. Sure, it might "intra implicit transaction" have changed those last 1200 row to equal, in my mind, but due to the lock table filling up, in reality would abort the transaction with nothing set. And the process would stalemate.

***Illustration 2*:**

In this example, let's say I have **288 rows** of the 50 Million row table that could be updated shown above. Due to the end-game problem described, I would often find a problem running this query **twice**:

```
update students set thing=id where thing!=id order by id desc limit 200 ;
```

But I would not have a problem with these:

```
update students set thing=id where thing!=id order by id desc limit 200;
update students set thing=id where thing!=id order by id desc limit 88 ;
```

### Solutions

There are many ways to solve this, including but not limited to:

A. The creation of another index on a column suggesting the data had been updated, perhaps a `boolean`. And incorporating that into the `where` clause. Yet on huge tables, the creation of somewhat temporary indexes may be out of the question.

B. Populating a 2nd table with yet to be cleaned `id's` could be another solution. Coupled with and [update with a join](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21152) pattern.

C. Dynamically changing the LIMIT value so as to not cause an overrun of the lock table. The overrun can occur when there are simply no more rows to UPDATE or DELETE (your operation), the LIMIT has not been reached, and the lock table fills up in a fruitless scan for more that simply don't exist (seen above in ***Illustration2***).

The main point of this answer is to offer an understanding of why it is happening. And for any reader to craft an end-game solution that fits their needs (versus,  at times, fruitless changes to system variables, reboots, and prayers).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to create an index on the `date` column. I had 170 million rows and was deleting 6.5 million rows. I ran into the same problem and solved it by creating `non-clustered` index on the column which I was using in the `WHERE` clause then I executed the delete query and it worked.
Delete the index if you don't need it for future.