# The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size, even after increasing buffer pool size

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to partition a table with 200 million records in it. And it throws exception as total number of locks exceeded the lock table size. I read few suggestions online and changed my.cnf file.Here are the configurations:

```
# PER CLIENT SETTINGS #
# bit high but I got tons of ram here #
sort_buffer_size                = 2M
read_buffer_size                = 2M
binlog_cache_size               = 1M
wait_timeout                    = 31536000
interactive_timeout             = 300
max_allowed_packet              = 12M
thread_stack                    = 128K
table_cache                     = 1024
myisam_sort_buffer_size         = 1M
tmp_table_size                  = 12M
max_heap_table_size             = 12M


# LOGGING #
log_queries_not_using_indexes  = 1
slow_query_log                 = 1
slow_query_log_file            = /var/lib/mysql/slowquery.log

# MyISAM #
key_buffer_size                = 32M
myisam_recover                 = FORCE,BACKUP

# SAFETY #
max_allowed_packet             = 16M
max_connect_errors             = 1000000


# BINARY LOGGING #
log_bin                        = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin
expire_logs_days               = 14
sync_binlog                    = 1

# CACHES AND LIMITS #
tmp-table-size                 = 32M
max-heap-table-size            = 32M
query-cache-type               = 0
query-cache-size               = 0
max-connections                = 500
thread-cache-size              = 50
open-files-limit               = 65535
table-definition-cache         = 1024
table-open-cache               = 2048

# INNODB #
innodb-flush-method            = O_DIRECT
innodb-log-files-in-group      = 2
innodb-log-file-size           = 512M
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit = 1
innodb-file-per-table          = 1
innodb-buffer-pool-size        = 40G
```

I have restarted mysql after making these changes. Still it throws the exception. My server has 12 cores and 48GB Ram and I can dedicate this server for this partitioning process for time being. are there any suggestions to bypass this exception(total number of locks exceeded)?

Comment: voted to move this question to dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

If you can dedicate this server for partitioning then lock the whole table with `LOCK TABLES` before partitioning. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/7066272/3182500