# What is the reason for "The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size"

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a table from a *simple* select statement that joins two tables and has a `group by .. having ..` clause.

The SQL statement returns a *The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size* error. In stack overflow, someone else has had the same problem and was advised to increase `innodb_buffer_pool_size`([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10912622/180275)). This is what I did, but I am still facing the same issue.

The select statement without create table statement runs perfectly and returns some 250 records.

I am wondering *why* I get this error. I am hard pressed to find a reason to lock anything in order to create a table. And I am also looking for a workable solution to create a table with a mere 250 records.

Comment: Can you link to the question you found with that advice?

Comment: @Barmar please see my edit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901108/the-total-number-of-locks-exceeds-the-lock-table-size)

Comment: @Rakesh, I have done what the (not accepted!) answers of that question advised - to no avail. Futhermore, I have also asked why I need locks to create a table. Thus, this cannot be a duplication of said questin.