# How to resize mysql parameters via command line

Tags: mysql, parameters, global

I tried to resize parameters using

```
set global parameter_name=size
```

from command line ,but it gives me error as

```
Error Code: 1238. Variable 'innodb_buffer_pool_size' is a read only variable
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696857/how-to-change-value-for-innodb-buffer-pool-size-in-mysql-on-mac-os

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set global innodb\_buffer\_pool\_size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19534144/how-to-set-global-innodb-buffer-pool-size)

Comment: i already checked these two links and made changes in my.ini file.that is ok, but i want resize through command line

Comment: i have also tried SET sort_buffer_size=10000;
SET @@local.sort_buffer_size=10000;
SET GLOBAL sort_buffer_size=1000000, SESSION sort_buffer_size=1000000;
SET @@sort_buffer_size=1000000;
SET @@global.sort_buffer_size=1000000, @@local.sort_buffer_size=1000000;

Comment: @oldskool,@philRoss but it gives me same error.

Answer (score 0):

'`read only`' variables are **read** only. That means, their values can't be changed dynamically by any means. You need to go to your my.cnf, change the initial value there and restart mysql process.

Comment: sir i m using amazon server RDS on that i dont have access to search my.cnf file and modify it.

Comment: Then you should refer to the RDS documentation. What version of mysql is running there? See also  the links above.